# openvpn in a bridge?

Tags: openvpn, bridge

I have a somewhat tricky proble to solve.

We have a wireless link between 2 building. One of them has an mikrotik and below there are some vlans. Some machines of one vlan need to use openvpn to connect to a remote private lan. I put a TP-Link WR1043ND (which those machines connect to)  with openwrt with ebtables just in case I need it.

I've configured openwrt in such a way that all ports belongs to the same vlan. My idea was to make things as transparent as I can.

It has a bridge as follows:

```
usr/sbin/brctl-full show br-lan 
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-lan          8000.f8d111565716       no              eth0.1
                                                        eth0.2
```

Also I've added an ebtables rule:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ipv4  -j DROP
```

So "bridge" has only one IP address. I've installed openvpn and I'm trying to bring up the tunnel but I can't still get working.

Sure, someone can says why don't you use the vpn on the mikrotik, there are some reasons, the first one is I have little experience with mikrotik and I'd want to have the vpn at hand :)

The problem is that openvpn is not working, because it is complaining that I have only one Ip Address on the server side. So I set up and alias interface with another IP address but is not working either:

```
: Rejected connection attempt from IP-Client-Side:37801 due to --remote setting
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Perhaps it looks easier I thought I've found the following article: "Using routing and OpenVPN not running on the default gateway" http://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting surely I'll take a look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Finaley I've found a way so this to work

I had to add some rule by hand after launch openvpn. I don't know why, but now it's working :)

FYI:

/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500

/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 192.168.200.1 peer 192.168.142.1

/sbin/ip route add 192.168.142.0/24 via 192.168.142.1